# Angular 1.5.0 with ES6 - controller export not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have a module based app. The app load de modules, while each module loads controller and router, and router loads view. The controller binding works just fine if I use like this:

```
...
module.controller('Ctrl',  function(){
  const vm = this
  // Controller stuff
});
...
```

But it doesn't if I try to load from an external file, like this:

```
// module.controller.js
function Ctrl(){
  // Controller stuff
}
export default Ctrl
```

And call like this:

```
// module.js
import controller from './module.controller.js'
...
module.controller(controller.name, controller)
...
```

Still `controller.name` is a valid `'Ctrl'` string and `controller` is a valid function. Is there something missing such as a different method of exporting the controller function or something?

Thanks

Comment: Are you receiving the correct data from this import? If you console the imported value, you can reach everything that you are using on the controller module declaration?

Comment: Yes, when I ~import controller from 'file.js'~ and try to log ~controller.name~ it prints the valid string and when I print ~controller~ it returns the valid function. But regarding the properties, I can only access values I have returned from the function, while angular controller should auto return ~this~.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to see that you are using `function` to create the controller, but you need to use a class, with a constructor in it. Dependencies are injected in this constructor and they can be accessed if you associate them as scope properties:

```
export default class Ctrl {
    /** @ngInject */
    constructor($timeout) {
        this.name = 'Ctrl';
        this.$timeout = $timeout;

        this.consoleName();
    }
    consoleName() {
        var vm = this;

        this.$timeout(function() {
            console.log(vm.name);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7fq4dnt9/

I recommend this article to compare the syntax and declarations:

https://medium.com/@daviddentoom/switching-to-es6-with-angular-1-x-is-easy-a08c40c2fc72#.e7i1avfqp.

Comment: That solved my problem in all cases I needed, thanks. But still, after some testing, it seems like some server config issue, because at some servers it worked without any change to my code while your suggestion worked on every case.